# Find all tasks marked as done today

Tags: org-mode

While in my agenda, I mark several TODOs as DONE as I complete them.

Is there a way to see what all was marked as DONE today?

Comment: In the agenda you can switch to log mode via the key `l`, which shows all items for today regardless of status.  However, if you have repeating tasks, marking them done moves them to a different date and so they will not show up here.