# Display "DONE" tasks of a specific day

Tags: org-mode

After setting `(setq org-log-done t)` which adds timestamp to done tasks.

```
** DONE a testing task :emacs:
CLOSED: [2019-08-29 Thu 09:37]
```

The problem is that the finished task is not displayed in agenda even though switch timestamp from inactivate to active.

If could not show the done jobs on agenda 
[find tasks markded today](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48647/find-all-tasks-marked-as-done-today)

How could filter the done tasks on a specific day?

Answer (score 3):

One way that's built-in is to use the agenda view to use the "logbook" journal of state changes with times that you can get org-mode to keep.

You can define logging for state transitions with your `org-todo-keywords` setings (there are a lot of options about what transitions to log -- see the documentation at https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes). The following is the example from the documentation, the "@" and "!" markers request these log entries to be created for some selected states:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO(t)" "WAIT(w@/!)" "|" "DONE(d!)" "CANCELED(c@)")))
```

You probably also want to keep those entries tidy by keeping them in a "drawer" with:

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

Once you've done that and you have a `:LOGBOOK:` drawer being maintained in your task,  you can view them in the agenda.

Do that by typing `v [` in your agenda (view inactive timestamps).

You can then skip back and forwards by with `b` and `f`.

Not directly related to the question, but if you're looking to track time and activity you should probably also investigate clocking (https://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-work-time.html), and `org-clock-into-drawer` to keep clock entries tidied in a similar way to state changes). You can then view times in the agenda with `v c` (clockcheck) or use "clocktables" to get time spent on tasks for timesheets etc.